# Extracting data that follows specific string only

Tags: python, regex

I have a file I want to extract data from using regex that looks like this :

```
RID:  RSS-130                                         SERVICE                        PAGE:              2   
REPORTING FOR:      100019912 SSSE                      INTSERVICE                    PROC DATE:   15SEP21   
ROLLUP FOR:          100076212 SSSE                          REPORT                        REPORT DATE: 15SEP21   
ENTITY:  1000208212 SSSE                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                      
 ACQT                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                      
   PUR                                                                                                                         
     SAME                      10SEP21                 120            12,263,518             19,48.5                        
                                                                                                                                      
   T PUR                                              120            12,263,518             19,48.5
```

The regex I wrote to extract the data :

```
regex_1 = PROC DATE:\s*(\w+).?*     # to get 15SEP21   
regex_2 = T PUR\s*([0-9,]*\s*[0-9,]*)  # to get the first two elements of the line after T PUR
```

This works but in the file I have multiple records just like this one, under different `RID:  RSS-130` for example `RID:  RSS-140`, I want to enforce extracting information only that follows `RID:  RSS-130` and `ACQT` and stop when that record is over and not carry on extracting data from what ever is under How can I do that?

Desired output would be :

`[(15SEP21;120;12,263,518)]` for the record that comes under `RID: RSS-130` and after `ACQT` only

Comment: FYI: Remove `.?*` as it is just some mess in your first regex. Also, if you only want to get 2 details from a block of text, you should not use two separate regexps. You need to *capture* these two substrings within one call to regex. The only thing needed is to define the stop condition for the search, what is the boundary pattern for a block of text. Is it `RID:\s+RSS-\d+`? Also, what is your code? And what is the expected output for the above input?

Comment: Hey @WiktorStribiżew thank you for your answer, `.?*` is there cause i intend to combine the two regex, as for the expected output i modified my question and added

Comment: Did the solution below work?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest leveraging a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) here:

```php
(?s)PROC DATE:\s*(?P<date>\w+)(?:(?!RID:\s+RSS-\d).)*T PUR\s+(?P<num>\d[.,\d]*)\s+(?P<val>\d[\d,]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rrijO3/2). *Details*:

- `(?s)` - an inline `re.S` / `re.DOTALL` modifier
- `PROC DATE:` -  a literal text
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?P<date>\w+)` - Group "date": one or more word chars
- `(?:(?!RID:\s+RSS-\d).)*` - any single char, zero or more but as many as possible occurrences, that does not start a `RID:\s+RSS-\d` pattern (block start pattern, `RID:`, one or more whitespaces, `RSS-` and a digit)
- `T PUR` - a literal string
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?P<num>\d[.,\d]*)` - Group "num": a digit and then zero or more  commas, dots and digits
- `\s+` - one or more digits
- `(?P<val>\d[\d,]*)` - Group "val": a digit and then zero or more commas or digits.

See the Python demo:

```py
import re
text = "RID:  RSS-130                                         SERVICE                        PAGE:              2   \nREPORTING FOR:      100019912 SSSE                      INTSERVICE                    PROC DATE:   15SEP21   \nROLLUP FOR:          100076212 SSSE                          REPORT                        REPORT DATE: 15SEP21   \nENTITY:  1000208212 SSSE                                                                                                 \n                                                                                                                                      \n                                                                                                                                      \n                                                                                                                                      \n                                                                                                                                      \n ACQT                                                                                                               \n                                                                                                                                      \n                                                                                                                                      \n   PUR                                                                                                                         \n     SAME                      10SEP21                 120            12,263,518             19,48.5                        \n                                                                                                                                      \n   T PUR                                              120            12,263,518             19,48.5"
rx = r"PROC DATE:\s*(?P<date>\w+)(?:(?!RID:\s+RSS-\d).)*T PUR\s+(?P<num>\d[.,\d]*)\s+(?P<val>\d[\d,]*)"
m = re.search(rx, text, re.DOTALL)
if m:
    print(m.groupdict())

# => {'date': '15SEP21', 'num': '120', 'val': '12,263,518'}
```

If you MUST check for `T PUR` after `ACQT`, modify the pattern to

```py
(?s)PROC DATE:\s*(?P<date>\w+)(?:(?!RID:\s+RSS-\d|ACQT).)*ACQT(?:(?!RID:\s+RSS-\d).)*T PUR\s+(?P<num>\d[.,\d]*)\s+(?P<val>\d[\d,]*)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rrijO3/3).